# How to fix webpack-pwa-manifest vulnerability?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, webpack, minimist

How to fix webpack-pwa-manifest@4.2.0 and minimist vulnerability. I tried by deleting node/modules and package-lock.json and do a fresh npm install but I have the same issue, any feedback is really appreciated.
Attached screenshots.
[image]

[image]

Comment: I think the best thing to do is report this to webpack-pwa-manifest. They might be able to change/update dependencies around to ensure a non-vulnerable version is included in the next version. You can also try to fork the project and fix it yourself and do a PR to help out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, the issue is on `minimist` (`webpack-pwa-manifest` submodule), and it's on version `0.0.8`. You can install the newest version of this module using resolution on package.json until the `webpack-pwa-manifest` update this module...

To add this resolution you just need to add this on you package.json:

`"resolutions": { "minimist": ">=1.2.3" }`

And run:

`npx npm-force-resolutions && npm install`